# Fedora 17 Data Card Installation error

Tags: fedora

I have installed fedora 17 recently and i am trying to install my aircell datacard
but i get following error message while installing

```
this is linux driver installtion
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.3-1.fc17.x86_64/build M=/tmp/ONDA_driver_install_V3.41 modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.5.3-1.fc17.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2
this  is customized kernel ,kernel version is: 3.5.3-1.fc17.x86_64
enter customize_driver_install function
cp: cannot stat `onda.ko': No such file or directory
FATAL: Module onda not found.
disselfirefox.pp driver_install.run nm.pp se End to /opt/Connection_Manager/driver
libsepol.scope_copy_callback: spamassassin: Duplicate declaration in module: type/attribute pyzord_exec_t (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.semanage_link_sandbox: Link packages failed (No such file or directory).
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed!
the return is 256
libsepol.scope_copy_callback: spamassassin: Duplicate declaration in module: type/attribute pyzord_exec_t (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.semanage_link_sandbox: Link packages failed (No such file or directory).
/usr/sbin/semodule:  Failed!
the return is 256
it's ok!
usermod: group 'netdev' does not exist
```

Please could somebody help me out on this

Answer (score 1):

You didn't install the `kernel-devel` package.